# What are the pygame.Surface.get_rect() key arguments?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm learning to use `pygame` in my programming course, but I'm confused with the `pygame.Surface.get_rect()` method. I see that it can take some keyword arguments but I can't find anywhere what they are. I've seen `get_rect(center=(num, num))` but I am trying to assign a top left corner coordinate. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 8):

The keyword arguments [are documented](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) as being applied to the rect's attributes. Those are documented in [the `pygame.Rect` page](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

> The Rect object has several virtual attributes which can be used to
>   move and align the Rect:
>
> ```
> x,y
> top, left, bottom, right
> topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
> midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
> center, centerx, centery
> size, width, height
> w,h
> ```
>
> All of these attributes can be assigned to:
>
> ```
> rect1.right = 10
> rect2.center = (20,30)
> ```
>
> Assigning to size, width or height changes the dimensions of the
>   rectangle; all other assignments move the rectangle without resizing
>   it. Notice that some attributes are integers and others are pairs of
>   integers.

So, if you want to get a rectangle the size of your image, with its top left at a certain point, you'd do:

```
my_surface.get_rect(topleft=some_point)
```

You could also pass separate `top` and `left` arguments (or `x` and `y`).